Who are the 'top five' leading/seminal authors/sources on the philosophy of intelligence, from the 19th to 21st centuries?
I am working to trace the nature of philosophical thought about intelligence over time, thinking that the overall body of thought has accelerated in 19th to 21st centuries, fueled by technological developments that enhanced intelligence research in other academic fields dealing with the study of intelligence (e.g. cognitive science).

Marvin Minsky's "Society of Mind" is worth a read. I'm not sure that philosophers have that much to contribute about intelligence, as compared to cognitive scientists and artificial general intelligence researchers. But some of what AI researchers have to say can be quite philosophical.

The concept of intelligence is too heterogeneous and "philosophy of intelligence" is not a formed field, depending on what is meant you will get very different top five. Phenomenological study of human thinking is one thing, computational theory of mind is another, artificial intelligence is yet another, etc. You'll have to narrow it down.
